# Insert a RDF data to Virtuoso by using dotNetRDF library in C# .Net

Tags: .net, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore, dotnetrdf

I'd like to know how I can insert a RDF (which is downloaded such a string) into Virtuoso by using dotNetRDF.

For example I've read the RDF data that you find on this link: "http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2.0005/rdf/object/full"

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:j.1="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
    xmlns:j.2="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/annotation#"
    xmlns:j.3="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm/cmr#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2.0005.02">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.print"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2.0005">
    <j.3:metsStructSuperDiv rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2"/>
    <j.3:lang rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#language">fr</j.3:lang>
    <j.3:lang rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#language">fra</j.3:lang>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/celex/31998R2278.FRA"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/uriserv/OJ.L_.1998.286.01.0013.01.FRA"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA"/>
    <j.3:lastModificationDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2014-04-04T10:21:30.312+02:00</j.3:lastModificationDate>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA">
    <j.0:uses rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/FRA"/>
    <j.0:expression_title_information_additional rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">CELEX1</j.0:expression_title_information_additional>
    <j.0:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Règlement (CE) n° 2278/98 de la Commission du 22 octobre 1998 déterminant la mesure dans laquelle les demandes de certificats d'importation introduites en octobre 1998 pour certains produits du secteur de la viande de porc peuvent être acceptées dans le cadre du régime prévu par le règlement (CE) n° 774/94 du Conseil portant ouverture et mode de gestion de certains contingents tarifaires communautaires pour la viande porcine et certains autres produits agricoles</j.0:title>
    <j.0:title_information_additional rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">CELEX1</j.0:title_information_additional>
    <j.0:expression_belongs_to_work rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007"/>
    <j.0:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">CELEX1</j.0:title>
    <j.0:expression_manifested_by_manifestation rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.print"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#expression"/>
    <j.0:expression_title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Règlement (CE) n° 2278/98 de la Commission du 22 octobre 1998 déterminant la mesure dans laquelle les demandes de certificats d'importation introduites en octobre 1998 pour certains produits du secteur de la viande de porc peuvent être acceptées dans le cadre du régime prévu par le règlement (CE) n° 774/94 du Conseil portant ouverture et mode de gestion de certains contingents tarifaires communautaires pour la viande porcine et certains autres produits agricoles</j.0:expression_title>
    <j.0:expression_uses_language rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/FRA"/>
    <j.2:build_info>cdm:CDM_2.1.7  tdm:1523  xslt:3945 saxon:9.0.0.1J JVM:1.6.0_29 metaconvJar:1.2.0 builddate:04/04/2014 01:00:03</j.2:build_info>
    <j.0:expression_manifested_by_manifestation rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.pdf"/>
    <j.0:belongs_to rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#legislation_secondary"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#work"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#resource_legal"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#regulation"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/FRA">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#language"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
    <j.1:inScheme rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language"/>
    <j.0:language_used_by_expression rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.pdf">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#manifestation"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/eli/reg/1998/2278/oj"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/celex/31998R2278"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.print">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#manifestation_official-journal_part"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#manifestation"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/fdc34ca7-6cbf-4f81-8bbd-e7255ccfa0c2.0005.01">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#manifestation"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_1998_286_R_0013_007.FRA.pdf"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And I've stored it (by using HttpWebRequest) in a string but I don't know how can I insert it to my Virtuoso by dotNetRDF. Any idea?

In addition, how can we set the UserAgent on QueryWithResultSet function? 
On this EndPoint : http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql I have to set UserAgent, else I can't get a query from.

Thanks

PS: I can't load RDF directly from the target server because there is a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: Have you read the `dotnetrdf` docs? [Writing RDF with `dotNetRDF`](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Writing-RDF), [Working with Triple Stores](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Working-With-Triple-Stores), [3rd Party Triple Store Integration](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration), [Virtuoso](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Storage-Virtuoso), [VirtuosoManager Class](https://dotnetrdf.github.io/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Storage_VirtuosoManager.htm)

Comment: 1. I don't want to write RDF and save in another file or stream
2. I'd like to save Data to an existing Graph and I don't need Saving graph!
3. It's my third project in Virtuoso, of cours I know Virtuoso and how can I connect to it by dotNetRDF. 
4. I can't write the RDF online directly to the server, because UserAgent setting is missed in dotNetRDF library.

Comment: @TallTed Do you have another idea ?
virtuoso.UpdateGraph("http://example.org/graph", null, new Triple[] { t }); Could help me but I don't know how can I convert RDF string to array of Triple!

Comment: You can extend `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` and override the `ApplyCustomRequestOptions()` method if you need to customise the `HttpWebRequest` such as by adding a `UserAgent` header.

Comment: It really isn't that difficult, added an answer that demonstrates this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` and override the `ApplyCustomRequestOptions()` method if you need to customise the `HttpWebRequest` such as by adding a `UserAgent` header:

```
public class MyCustomEndpoint : SparqlRemoteEndpoint
{
  // Define appropriate constructors with the parameters you need e.g.
  public MyCustomEndpoint(Uri endpointUri)
    : base(endpointUri) { }     

  protected override ApplyCustomRequestOptions(HttpWebRequest request)
  {
     request.UserAgent = "My Custom User Agent"
  } 
}
```

The `ApplyCustomRequestOptions()` method is called before each `HttpWebRequest` is submitted so can be used to do any customisation needed.  Then simply use `MyCustomEndpoint` in place of `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` as needed.

You can always refer to the [SparqlRemoteEndpoint](https://dotnetrdf.github.io/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Query_SparqlRemoteEndpoint.htm) documentation for more detail of available methods and properties.

Comment: there is always a problem 502 BadGateway. I think it's not related to my query and they have added a Firwall for doing query.

Comment: Is there any way for replacing importation data with ISQL workspace by c# syntax?

Comment: If you have a different question then you should create a new question! Comments are only intended for clarifications on a question/answer

Comment: How to Debug HTTP Communication in dotNetRDF - https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/HowTo-Debug-HTTP-Communication

Comment: I've tested with "Debug HTTP Communication in dotNetRDF" I've got an error message which told me that they blocked me to access to this service. I'd like to know how they can block this service? Is it a specific service? How can I do the same on my virtuoso? The endpoint is: http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql

Comment: Did SparqlRemoteEndpoint try to modify the parameters in the headers of the customized SPARQL client ?

Comment: Since you haven't provided the error message, please edit your question to include this if it is relevant, it is hard to say. The code will set a variety of common options but any customisation that your code makes would take precedence. Service providers can block clients and users for any number of reasons, if you want to understand why you were blocked that is something you would have to ask the providers of the service